# Using RestKit to perform a synchronous request

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, afnetworking, synchronous

```
- (BOOL)do_a_Restkit_request_and_return_a_boolean
{
     [manager postObject:nil path:@"/mypath" parameters:@{@"password":password} success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
          myResult = [mappingResult firstObject] == 5;
      } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      }];

      return myResult;

}
```

Hello I would like to make a RestKit call like the above Synchronous so as to return myResult after the call of the Success block.

Comment: RestKit is built on AFNetworking, which doesn't do this.  Can you post your reasoning for wanting to return synchronously?  If you can at all possibly rewrite your code where the completion block calls a method that triggers the behavior you need, that would almost certainly be better.

Comment: I am passing this code to a block variable. The block is used synchronously by a library to return a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an approach like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = // create a request…
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];

BOOL myResult = NO;

if (!operation.error) {
      myResult = [operation.mappingResult firstObject] == 5;
}

return myResult;
```

Notes:

- The completion blocks are called *after* the operation is finished, so if you provide success/failure blocks, they won't be called until *after* the method returns

  - (This is why I suggest you pass `nil` into the completion blocks.)
- `waitUntilFinished` will block whatever thread you're on, so make sure it's not the main thread.
- If you need help creating `request`, see [Creating Request Objects in the RKObjectManager Class Reference](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#task_Creating%20Request%20Objects).
- Again, if you can rewrite your code to work asynchronously, that will probably be better than this solution.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! The only drawback is that you cannot post an object easily though, only parameters.

Comment: @ageorgios You should be able to post an object by making a request using `multipartFormRequestWithObject:method:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:`

Comment: Corollary is that there's a `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` equivalent for Core Data backed RestKit users.

Comment: I've been using MLPAutoComplete (https://cocoapods.org/pods/MLPAutoCompleteTextField) and that control calls the method to match the string (asynchronously). So, this approach of blocking for the response and returning the response is ideal in my case as the main thread is not blocked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either embrace the asynchronous nature of network communication and background processing of the response, or use a different API / technology specifically for making synchronous requests. RestKit and AFNetworking are based more around the former.

Embracing asynchronous is the best option...

That said, you could use RestKit to create the `NSURLRequest`, then use `NSURLConnection` to synchronously download the response, then use `RKMapperOperation` to perform the mapping (and wait for completion with `addOperations:waitUntilFinished:`).