# Restkit 0.24.1 POST to Server and get response synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, restkit

does any one know how to receive response of posted array synchronously?
here i have:

```
[manager postObject:objectArray path:@"" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@", result.firstObject);
    res = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[result array]];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (operation.error) {...}
```

but i want get `[result array];` without any delay

Comment: This might help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20596375/3617012

Comment: @iOSX tnx but this question is about GET Not POST

Comment: No, RestKit only does asynchronous...

Comment: @Wain can you tell me why?! tnq

Comment: Its core to the design so you don't block the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to block current thread

```
__block BOOL operationDone = NO;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:nil
                                      path:path
                                parameters:parameters
                                   success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *blockMappingResult) {

                                           // Do something

                                           operationDone = YES;
                                       }
                                   failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                           // Do something

                                           operationDone = YES;
                                       }];

while(!operationDone) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```